# AngularJS Manually Render Controller and Template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to implement a plugin system in angularjs that would allow users to configure which  "widgets" they will see on a certain page. Each widget is defined by a controller and a template(url). Is it possible to create a directive that instantiates a controller, invokes it with a template and transcludes the resulting content?

The goal is something like this:

```
<div class="widget" ng-repeat="widget in widgets">
    <widget controller="widget.controller" templateUrl="widget.templateUrl"></widget>
</div>
```

Comment: This is in essence what `ngView` does; though your use case is a little simpler, you may find its [source code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngView.js) helpful. Basically, you fetch, append to the DOM, and then `$compile` your template and then assign the controller: `element.children().data('$ngControllerController', controller);`. If I have time later today I'll post a more complete response.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

There are two ways to do this; one uses the helper directives already available (like `ngInclude` and `ngController`) and the second is manual; the manual version *might* be faster, but I cannot be sure.

**The Easy Way:**

The easy method is to simple create a new element with `ngController` and `ngInclude` attributes, append it to the directive's element, and then `$compile` it:

```js
var html = '<div ng-controller="'+ctrl+'" ng-include="'+tpl+'"></div>';
element.append(html);
$compile( element.contents() )( scope );
```

**The Manual Way:**

The manual way is to do what these directives would themselves do in turn; this logic is very similar to what `ngView` does (though without the complexity). We fetch the template, storing it in `$templateCache`, and then append it to the DOM. We create a new child scope and instantiate the provided controller with it and assign that controller to the element. Finally, we `$compile` it:

```js
$http.get( tpl, { cache: $templateCache } )
.then( function( response ) {
  templateScope = scope.$new();
  templateCtrl = $controller( ctrl, { $scope: templateScope } );
  element.html( response.data );
  element.children().data('$ngControllerController', templateCtrl);
  $compile( element.contents() )( templateScope );
});
```

(Note that there is no garbage collection here, which you would need to implement if the widgets change)

Here is a Plunker demonstrating both methods: http://plnkr.co/edit/C7x9C5JgUuT1yk0mBUmE?p=preview

Comment: This looks like a great solution, it's clear and logical, the problem with the 'easy way' is that the ng-include is not getting evaluated, it does load the controller :)

Comment: This line is great: `$http.get( tpl, { cache: $templateCache } )
.then( function( response ) {...)`. Thanks!

Comment: This does not work for me unless I call `scope.$apply()`

Comment: @Simone That should only be necessary if you leave the AngularJS lifecycle at some point, which the code above does not do. See the Plunker. What have you changed from the above? Can you post a plunker of your own showing the problem?

Comment: Well the "easy way" does not show in which context it is called

Comment: @Simone True, but directives are the *only* acceptable place for DOM manipulation to occur - anywhere else is misusing AngularJS. So it should never be an issue, but I'm happy to help if you provide more information.

Comment: In my case I was trying to populate a Google Maps InfoWindow with the HTML generated by compiling an angular template and populating it with values coming from a scope. I was basically trying to use angular as a templating language, which worked well as soon as I called `$apply` on the scope.

Comment: This is awesome. However, I don't understand what associating the controller with the `'$ngControllerController'` .data() key does. I see that it's supposed to associate the controller with the element's children (or vice versa), but looking through the Angular source, I can't see how that happens and, as far as I can tell, the Plnkr still works as intended with that line commented out. Can anyone explain what this line's doing?

Comment: @RichPollock Very late answer here. I had the same question and had a quick look through the source. I found that it's set to enable the jqLite `controller` method to function correctly (see `angular.element`). I didn't dig too much deeper than that though. https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/jqLite.js#L439

Comment: Any ideas on what sort of garbage collection is required with the second solution? We're using this method to render a context panel so are swapping the template and controller depending on the property being edited.