# How do I assign an attribute to ng-controller in a directive's template in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller, angularjs-ng-include

I have a custom attribute directive (i.e., `restrict: "A"`) and I want to pass two expressions (using `{{...}}`) into the directive as attributes. I want to pass these attributes into the directive's template, which I use to render two nested `div` tags -- the outer one containing `ng-controller` and the inner containing `ng-include`. The `ng-controller` will define the controller exclusively used for the template, and the `ng-include` will render the template's HTML.

An example showing the relevant snippets is below.

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-controller="appController">
    <custom-directive ctrl="templateController" tmpl="template.html"></custom-directive>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
function appController($scope) {
    // Main application controller
}

function templateController($scope) {
    // Controller (separate from main controller) for exclusive use with template
}

app.directive('customDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            ctrl: '@',
            tmpl: '@'
        },
        // This will work, but not what I want
        // Assigning controller explicitly
        template: '<div ng-controller="templateController">\
                       <div ng-include="tmpl"></div>\
                   </div>'
        // This is what I want, but won't work
        // Assigning controller via isolate scope variable from attribute
        /*template: '<div ng-controller="ctrl">\
                         <div ng-include="tmpl"></div>\
                     </div>'*/
    };
});
```

It appears that explicitly assigning the controller works. However, I want to assign the controller via an isolate scope variable that I obtain from an attribute located inside my custom directive in the HTML.

I've fleshed out the above example a little more in the Plunker below, which names the relevant directive `contentDisplay` (instead of `customDirective` from above). Let me know in the comments if this example needs more commented clarification:

### [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/1mIks2ROM44h9SM9pejl?p=preview)

Using an explicit controller assignment (uncommented template code), I achieve the desired functionality. However, when trying to assign the controller via an isolate scope variable (commented template code), it no longer works, throwing an error saying `'ctrl' is not a function, got string`.

The reason why I want to vary the controller (instead of just throwing all the controllers into one "master controller" as I've done in the Plunker) is because I want to make my code more organized to maintain readability.

The following ideas may be relevant:

- Placing the `ng-controller` tags inside the template instead of wrapping it around `ng-include`.
- Using one-way binding (`'&'`) to execute functions instead of text binding (`'@'`).
- Using a link function instead of / in addition to an isolate scope.
- Using an element/class directive instead of attribute directive.
- The priority level of `ng-controller` is lower than that of `ng-include`.
- The order in which the directives are compiled / instantiated may not be correct.

While I'm looking for direct solutions to this issue, I'm also willing to accept workarounds that accomplish the same functionality and are relatively simple.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can dynamically write a `template` key using `scope`, but you certainly do so within the `link` function. You can imitate that quite succinctly with a series of built-in Angular functions: `$http`, `$controller`, `$compile`, `$templateCache`.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/sheLasH4D3ROhzOTURQf?p=preview)

Relevant code:

```
    link: function( scope, element, attrs )
    {
      $http.get( scope.tmpl, { cache: $templateCache } )
        .then( function( response ) {
          templateScope = scope.$new();
          templateCtrl = $controller( scope.ctrl, { $scope: templateScope } );
          element.html( response.data );
          element.children().data('$ngControllerController', templateCtrl);
          $compile( element.contents() )( templateScope );
        });
    }
```

Inspired strongly by [this similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16343458/angularjs-manually-render-controller-and-template).

Comment: Thanks for the workaround! A follow-up question: You mention that "`template` may not have enough access to `scope`" -- how can a component have only _partial_ access to `scope`? Shouldn't it be all or nothing? In words more specific to my example, how can `tmpl` be accessible by the `template` key, but not `ctrl`?

Comment: Sorry that was a bit unclear, I just mean I don't know of a way to make a string such as `'<div ng-controller="' + scope.tmpl +'" />'`. (Note the reference to `scope`; in a normal `template` string you would let Angular process each scope property internally.