# AngularJS manually render controller and template containing ng-switch directive

Tags: angularjs, ng-switch

Following the advise of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16345058/740996), I've been trying to render a controller and template manually, but I can't get it to work when the template contains an `ng-switch` directive. Any ideas?

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kynZm/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `ng-switch` directive was being compiled before my link function had a chance to run and was linking to the `$rootScope`. Moving the `$compile` call to the compile phase of the directive seemed to do the trick.

http://jsfiddle.net/z8uXg/