# angularjs load template on startup conditionally in controller

Tags: angularjs

In my Ionic Framework app I need to load some templates under some conditions given from the database on startup. For example if there are user login informations stored in the database the app should go to the normal template. If not it should go to a template where the login credentials are requested from the user. I'm handling the conditions in a startup controller like this:

```
.controller('StartProcessCtrl', function ($scope,$ionicPlatform, StartProcess) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(StartProcess.userExists()) {
      //load the normal template
    }
    else {
     //load the credentials template
    }
  });
})
```

In this case StartProcess is a factory which communicates with the SQLite database.

My problem is that I'm using the  `$urlRouterProvider` like here:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/startProcess');
```

So it always starts in startProcess template. I want to get a level abstraction so if there are credential saved it should go to the normal app with side menu templates and so on and if not it should open the credentials template without the side menu on left.

Comment: no idea about ionic, but those template in angular should be done in route resolve

Comment: YOU can you please show an example in how to do it in route resolve with conditions from a factory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution, while keeping it in your startup controller, would be to route the user to the desired location using the [$location](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location) service, example:

```
.controller('StartProcessCtrl', function ($scope, $location, $ionicPlatform, StartProcess) {
      $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
        if(StartProcess.userExists()) {
          //load the normal template
          $location.url('/user');
        }
        else {
         //load the credentials template
         $location.url('/credentials');
        }
      });
    })
```

Outside of that, you'd need to basically use the $http service to get the template, compile it and bind the current scope (or a new scope to it), grab the html container holding the template and update the template container manually. Take a look at this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16343458/angularjs-manually-render-controller-and-template) on details on how to do it with this method.