# Angularjs ng-include html pages

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

Hi I want to include different html pages, 
 in my project there are 10 tiles clicking on 1 tile related html have to be included. like this if I click any one in 10 tiles particular page  should be displayed. Any Solution for this

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16343458/angularjs-manually-render-controller-and-template

Comment: Would be great if you could provide some sample of what you have already done

Answer (score 0):

If you want to follow rest api, you should change the URL on click.
Now implement ng-view for including specific html in the view on the basis of url.
You can learn routing here :https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute

Comment: Other than ng-Route any options,Please let me know

Comment: Use ng-include itself and that said use ng-show and ng-hide to toggle between html's