# Manually loading template with controller in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates

In AngularJS I'm trying to manually load a template that uses a predefined controller.

I call a WebApi to get a list of available templates. When this list is received I should load each template onto the page. Each template also uses an AngularJS controller so the connection between the template and the preloaded controller must work.

After some googling I ended up on this previous (and somewhat old) question: [AngularJS Manually Render Controller and Template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16343458/angularjs-manually-render-controller-and-template)

It seems to do exactly what I want, but it has a directive that uses more parameters than I need. Also, I don't have directives for my templates. I just can't wrap my head around how to get it to do what I want.

How can I get `ExampleTemplateToLoad.html` to be loaded by code, inserted into `div#LoadedTemplates` while functioning like a normal template using a controller?

**main.js**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [.....]);
myApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', { templateUrl : '/mainTemplate.html' });
});

myApp.controller('mainController', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('/api/getListOfTemplateScripts').success(function (data) {
        // This returns a list of scripts that should be loaded
        // Scripts are loaded using https://github.com/ded/script.js
        // These scripts show up in "Sources" in Chrome Developer Tools,
        // and any syntax errors in these scripts are also displayed in
        // the console, so the script is definitely loaded
        angular.forEach(data, function (scriptFile, key) {
            $script(scriptFile, function() {
                console.log(scriptFile + " loaded");
            });
        });
    })
    .then(function() {
        $http.get('/api/getListOfTemplate').success(function (data) {
            // This returns a list that includes ExampleTemplateToLoad.html
            // The template should then be loaded into div#LoadedTemplates
            angular.forEach(data, function (templateFile, key) {
                // This is logged *after* "scriptToLoad loaded" in the console
                console.log('Loading template ' + templateFile);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

**mainTemplate.html**

```
<div ng-controller="mainController">
    <div id="LoadedTemplates"></div>
</div>
```

**ExampleTemplateToLoad.html**

```
<div ng-controller="loadedTemplateController">
    <!-- Do whatever the template needs to do, using variables defined
         in $scope as it would normally do -->
</div>
```

**ExampleTemplateControllerToLoad.js**

```
myApp.controller('loadedTemplateController', function ($scope, $http) {
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if ur supposed to be modifying DOM from a controller but I'd try binding your "LoadedTemplates" to a variable (using ng-model) and in the controller, once you get the dynamic template back from the $http.get, get a reference to the div, i.e.

```
var target = $document[0].getElementById('LoadedTemplates')
```

and then do something along the lines of:

```
element.append(htmlReturnedByService);
$compile( element.contents() )( $scope );
```

Haven't tested, but maybe this helps :D

Comment: First error in console is `scope is not defined`. If I try to replace `scope` with `$scope` I get `Argument 'loadedTemplateController' is not a function, got undefined`. This is due to the lazy loading of the template's script file. If I put the controller in `main.js` it works. I'm updating the code above to also show lazy loading of scripts.

Comment: Though your browser might be loading the script, the controller has to be registered in your angular app. Try using $controllerProvider.register instead of $script?

Comment: How do I use `$controllerProvider.register` when all I have is a link to a JS file?

Comment: Never mind to the last comment. If I, in myApp.config save a reference to $controllerProvider.register, I can use that reference in my lazy loaded JS file instead of myApp.controller, and now it works. Now to get this to work in a directive, as you are correct in saying the DOM shouldn't be modified from a controller.

Comment: @GTHvidsten well, glad I'm helping a bit :)

Comment: Your bit definitely pointed me in the right direction, and now I have a directive working that does exactly what I wanted to to. I'll see if I can get a working JSFiddle going and link it later. Thanks :)

Comment: Here's a working plunker example: http://plnkr.co/edit/3kMPuSHmDuahhSFA0Nuq?p=preview